# Sql join 1 instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, distinct

I require some help with my very shaky sql skills.

Say I have the following select statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.ProjectId,
    p.Title,
    i.Name,
    p.StartDate,
    p.EndDate,
    ped.ProjectEthicsDocumentId,
    st.Description AS StatusText
FROM
    dbo.Project p
    inner join dbo.WorkflowHistory w ON p.ProjectId = w.ProjectId
    left join dbo.ProjectInstitution pi ON pi.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
    left join dbo.Institution i ON i.InstitutionId = pi.InstitutionId
    left join dbo.ProjectEthicsDocument ped on p.ProjectId = ped.ProjectId
    left join dbo.Status st ON p.StatusId = st.StatusId
```

This will return all the projects and other relevant details from the relevant tables. Now, say I have 2 institutions for 'Project A'. This statement will return 2 rows for 'Project A', one for each institution. How do I set it so that it only returns the first row of each project it finds? I want one instance of every project with say the first institution found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move selecting institution name to a subquery. This way you it doesn't affect how other tables are joined.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.ProjectId,
    p.Title,
    (SELECT TOP 1 i.Name FROM dbo.Institution i 
     INNER JOIN dbo.ProjectInstitution pi ON i.InstitutionId = pi.InstitutionId
     WHERE pi.ProjectId = p.ProjectId) AS Name,
    p.StartDate,
    p.EndDate,
    ped.ProjectEthicsDocumentId,
    st.Description AS StatusText
FROM
    dbo.Project p
    inner join dbo.WorkflowHistory w ON p.ProjectId = w.ProjectId
    left join dbo.ProjectEthicsDocument ped on p.ProjectId = ped.ProjectId
    left join dbo.Status st ON p.StatusId = st.StatusId
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is probably with the `row_number()` function:

```
select *
from (SELECT DISTINCT p.ProjectId, p.Title, i.Name, p.StartDate,p.EndDate,
             ped.ProjectEthicsDocumentId, st.Description AS StatusText,
             row_number() over (partition by p.ProjectId order by i.InstitutionId) as seqnum
      FROM dbo.Project p
           inner join dbo.WorkflowHistory w ON p.ProjectId = w.ProjectId
           left join dbo.ProjectInstitution pi ON pi.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
           left join dbo.Institution i ON i.InstitutionId = pi.InstitutionId
           left join dbo.ProjectEthicsDocument ped on p.ProjectId = ped.ProjectId
            left join dbo.Status st ON p.StatusId = st.StatusId
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This will only work if other joins do not cause more duplicates.

Comment: @Szymon . . . Can you elaborate?  This returns one row per project, regardless of the number of rows produced by the query.

Comment: What I meant is that other joins, e.g. to `dbo.ProjectEthicsDocument` might produce duplicates for a single project as there may be many rows in `dbo.ProjectEthicsDocument` for each project. It may be required to return more then one row per project but only one institution.

Comment: @Szymon . . . To me at least, the question seems ambiguous, but I fully understand your interpretation (and it seems to agree with what the OP really wants).

Comment: I agree it's not very clear. Your solution will work in most scenarios, I would say. I upvoted it as a good one.

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
;with cte as
(
<your select statement> `,`
    Row_number() over(partition by <column that has 2 records> order by ProjectId) as rn
)
--then do this
 select * from cte where rn=1
```